# Is it possible to handle incorrect input with multiple raw_input lines and one while loop - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

If you have a while loop with two raw_input lines, where you want each raw_input line to be repeated until a correct input is provided AND you also want the loop to continue until a specific outcome is achieved; is this even doable in Python without a goto option?

```
#For example:
while True:
    a = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
    #Hypothetically assuming "Sam" is the only acceptable answer
    if a not in ["Sam"]:
        print "Error, try again."
    else:
        b = raw_input("How old are you?: ")
        #Hypothetically assuming 28 is the only acceptable answer
        if b not in [28]:
            print "Error, try again."
        else:
            continue
            #no break out of loop provided, this is just a quick hypothetical
```

This is a pretty quick example (and not the best...), but it's just to give the gist of what I am trying to do with my code (complete beginner here). As you can see, the first error would work out just fine as things would loop back to the beginning and the first raw_input line, but an error on the second raw_input line would go also back to the first raw_input line (is there any way to repeat in the middle of the while loop where the second raw_input line is?) I'd like to try and salvage my code if possible, so if there is any way to make things work using this awfully long while loop, I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Add a loop for each block you'd like to repeat.

Comment: TigerhawkT3, thanks for the suggestion, but that wouldn't work in my case (I believe?), as I need my code (looks nothing like the example above) to continuously loop through both blocks. Wouldn't creating multiple loops stop the previous ones from running, once each new one begins?

Comment: No; putting the code to be repeated into a loop is standard practice, and pretty much the only way to go if you want to avoid recursion. You might want to look for some tutorials and guides focusing on loops and input.

Comment: Got it to work with separate loops, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant albeit little advanced solution -

```
def ask_questions():
    yield "Sam" == raw_input("What is your name?: ")
    yield "28"  == raw_input("How old are you?: ")

while True:
    repeat = False

    for answer in ask_question():
        if not answer:
            repeat = True
            break

    if not repeat:
        break
```

Comment: hspandher, thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't think that would work in my case because I need both of the raw_input lines along with their associated code, to repeat continuously until a specific condition is met (i.e. I wouldn't want one while loop to end and another one to start).

Comment: There's a bug in last one... fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable for keeping track of which question is due, like this:

```
def ask(question, validator):
    a = input(question)
    return a if validator(a) else None

progress = 0
while progress < 2:
    if progress == 0:
        ok = a = ask("What is your name?: ", lambda a: a in ["Sam"])
    else:
        ok = b = ask("How old are you?: ", lambda b: b in [28])
    if ok == None:
        print ("Error, try again.")
    progress += int(ok != None)
```

#### Alternative

You could initialise the answers as `None` and keep going until the last answer is not `None`, while asking the questions that still have no no-None answer value.

You could raise an exception if the validation fails for an answer:

```
def ask(question, validator):
    a = input(question)
    if not validator(a):
        raise ValueError
    return a 

progress = 0
a = None
b = None
while b == None:
    try:
        if a == None: a = ask("What is your name?: ", lambda x: x in ["Sam"]) 
        if b == None: b = ask("How old are you?: ", lambda x: x in [28])
    except ValueError:
        print ("Error, try again")

print (a, b)
```